# Sending SMS, MMS messages from mobile device and getting that message to a Java application server

Tags: sms, mms

I've been tasked with a project where the customer would like to send SMS, MMS messages from a mobile device.  They would like to have a dedicated phone number to send these messages to.  We would like these messages get routed through a gateway so it can be processed in a Java Application Server and have the server generate a response that will make its way back to the users mobile device.  The server side of this will be done in Java.

I'm new to this and trying to understand the best approach.  Please let me know what services and APIs are available that will allow me to do this.  It seems like there are plenty of services available to get the message from the server to the phone, but I'm not clear on the mechanism for getting the message from the device routed to the Java application server.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

You could get yourself an old Nokia 3210 or something with a data cable and connect it to a server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of companies that can provide a phone number to receive incoming sms messages as well as send them (not sure about MMS; that is a different story).  One of them is Clickatell.  They have a variety of API's you can use from Java.

http://www.clickatell.com/products/gateway.php

Answer (score 0):

There are some services which allow you to define a callback URL, so when their server receives an SMS, they forward the data to you via HTTP POST. Of course, there are several proprietary protocols, and SMPP (e.g. http://opensmpp.logica.com/), but that's a lot more complicated.

An example of such a service is http://www.textmagic.com/app/pages/en/products/bulk-sms-gateway-api